# Android - Make csv / txt file remain after update

Tags: android, csv, save, load

```
public void saveGame()   {
        String filename = "pdata.csv";
        System.out.println("Saving Game pdata...");
        File outFile = new File(filename);
        try {
            // Name + UserInfo + CVList+
            FileOutputStream os = openFileOutput(String.valueOf(outFile), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(os); //set up a writer
            printWriter.println("47*4,Sound Name,Win,Total,Country,Name");//print it

~~~[Code skipped]~~~
            printWriter.flush();
            printWriter.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
            System.out.println("Error saving");
        }
    }
```

This is the code that writes my array into .csv file.
Content doesn't matter much, but it contains user data and it is loaded/modified/saved everytime app runs.

But I figured if I save this file at "Context.MODE_PRIVATE", everytime app updates or reinstalls this file gets reset as well.
But I want this file not to be reset when Application gets updated.
(Like how SharedPreference data doesn't change or disappear after update)

How can I do that?

Comment: Define reinstall.  If you completely uninstall and reinstall an app, this is expected-  all files are deleted when its uninstalled.  A file written should persist through a mere update though.

Comment: Wait.. Okay that confuses me.

Comment: Okay, so files saved in "Context.MODE_PRIVATE" should remain after App gets re-installed? (Through Google Play or Android Studio re-build...). Okay I think my bug lies somewhere else then. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If it gets updated without being uninstalled, yes. If you uninstall it then reinstall, it will be deleted

Comment: @1011011 Did you manage to find a solution on that? I have the same issue, I am using the "Context.MODE_PRIVATE" but after app upgrade the file gets reset.